# Grunt conditional option

Tags: pug, gruntjs

I'm attempting to create a Jade task that will have a build and dev task that have very similar options, except a dev boolean, and a different destination. The simplest way I've been able to achieve this is:

```
jade: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            data: {
                dev: true, // dev true
                config: ...,
                pkg: ...,
                helpers: ...
            }
        },
        files: [{
            dest: '<%= config.workingDir %>',
            ...
        }]
    },
    build: {
        options: {
            data: {  // no dev
                config: ...,
                pkg: ...,
                helpers: ...
            }
        },
        files: [{
            dest: '<%= config.buildDir %>',
            ...
        }]
    }
}
```

There's considerable repetition in this though, particularly if I want to add more options down the track. So I'm trying to create one build task that will work both from command line and from a watch task.

The closest I've gotten is this setup, where I can run `grunt jade --dev` from the command line but can't set the dev boolean in the watch task.

```
build: {
    options: {
        data: {
            dev: '<%= grunt.option("dev") %>',
            config: ...,
            pkg: ...,
            helpers: ...
        }
    },
    files: [{
        dest: '<%= grunt.option("dev") ? config.workingDir : config.buildDir %>',
        ...
    }]
}
```

The watch task:

```
watch: {
    jade: {
        ...
        tasks: ['jade'] // the option is false
    }
}
```

I've also attempted to create a custom task that sets the option and then runs watch, which when listening to the watch event I can see the option is correctly set

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', 'Grunt dev mode', function(){
    grunt.option('dev', true);
    grunt.task.run('watch');
});

grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
    console.log(grunt.option('dev')); // true
});
```

Even though the log shows the dev boolean as true the wrong task options are being passed. So, with all that said, am I going about setting options the right way or am I just stuck with having a build and dev task that repeat the same information?

I've also tried using the grunt.util._.expand method with little success.
`data: "<%= grunt.util._.extend(jade.options.data, {dev: true}) %>",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [`options`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#options) at the `task` level that will serve as the default and then further specify `target` (dev vs build) specific `options` at the `target` level.  That way you avoid repeating the same configuration between multiple `targets`:

```
jade: {
    options : {
        config: ...,
        pkg: ...,
        helpers: ...
    },
    dev: {
        options: {
            dev : true
        },
        files: [{
            dest: '<%= config.workingDir %>',
            ...
        }]
    },
    build: {
        files: [{
            dest: '<%= config.buildDir %>',
            ...
        }]
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Based on the comment that in the `jade` case the options all need to be in `data`, and if the method above was used, the local `data` would completely override the global `data`, you could do this since the Gruntfile.js is just JavaScript:

```
var dataConfigBuild = {
    config: ...,
    pkg: ...,
    helpers: ...
};

//use your favorite way of "cloning" an object
var dataConfigDev = {};
for(var propName in dataConfigBuild) {
  dataConfigDev[propName] = dataConfigBuild[propName];
}

//and add the dev specific stuff
dataConfigDev.dev = true;
```

And then use like this in your task configuration:

```
jade: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            data : dataConfigDev
        },
        files: [{
            dest: '<%= config.workingDir %>',
            ...
        }]
    },
    build: {
        options : {
            data : dataConfigBuild
        },
        files: [{
            dest: '<%= config.buildDir %>',
            ...
        }]
    }
}
```

Note, this code is not tested.

As a side note, the reason you are not seeing your not seeing the expected config in the `watch` related code is most likely because you need to set [`spawn : false`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed).

Comment: I believe that overwrites and not expands the options (I'm not 100% on that though) but in this case it's the options.data property that I need to have the extra for so that it passes through to Jade.

Comment: The update was a good idea. I was trying to stick with, what I thought, was the Grunt way of doing it. I was hoping to avoid repeating the file option but it seems like the best option. Thanks.

Comment: I missed the part about spawn: false. That has actually sorted my issue and I can use the single task like the second option.