# Grunt build folder whose name is passed in command?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have a folder structure like:

```
folder 1
---build
---src

folder 2
---build
---src
```

Now, the grunt command should be such that:

```
grunt build <folder_name>
```

so that it builds the particular folder. Copies the code from src to build inside the folder.
Example,

```
grunt build folder 1
```

Is there any way to do this?
I checked passing arguments, but that is the last option.

Do we have grunt plugins are there for this purpose.

Also if possible we can have,

```
grunt build:folder 1
```

These are the two ways I am supposed to write grunt commands.

Comment: did you got any solution for the same ?

Comment: not exactly but I think this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623739/pass-options-to-a-grunt-task-while-running-it