# Run single test in protractor selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor

How to run single test in protractor selenium.

```
describe('Login page', function() {

beforeEach(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
});

it('should contain navigation items', function(){
  //test case code here
});

it('should login the user successfully', function(){ 
  //test case code here
})
});
```

I would like to run only single test. I can run it using `fit` but I would like to do it from command line and without changing test.

Also how can I run singe test using Grunt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [*`--grep` command-line argument*](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/cli.js#L64):

```
protractor conf.js --grep="navigation"
```

Comment: Hi, this is solving my purpose but I am getting other tests as Pending in result and xml report is showing other tests as well. ANy way to avoid it?

Comment: @rohitkadam19 glad to hear it helps. Are you using `jasmine-reporters`, specifically terminal and junit reporters?

Comment: yes, I am using `jasmin-reporters` and al so I am running it using Grunt-protractor. Can we use it with grunt and protractor?

Comment: @rohitkadam19 sure, reporters are configured inside the protractor config's `onPrepare()`. I mean that these issues can actually be `jasmine-reporters`-specific..try creating an issue in it's issue tracker https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/issues or post a separate question here about the reporters and grep option..

Comment: I have created issue - https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/issues/118. and how can I run --grep option with Grunt in protractor. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you can make use of passing your grep values as a task argument, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623739/pass-options-to-a-grunt-task-while-running-it and set the "grep" inside grunt-protractor-runner task options (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#options) ..not tested..